# how to get status code from logstash http filter

Tags: logstash

I am now using logstash [https filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html#plugins-filters-http-headers)

my filter part is as below

```
filter {
  http {
    url => "someUrl"
    verb => "GET"
    target_body => "apiResponse"
    target_headers => "apiResponseHeader"
  }
}
```

with http filter, I can't get HTTP response status codes

is there anyway to get HTTP status code from http filter?

---

target_headers give me back only this info

```
             "responseHeader" => {
        "transfer-encoding" => "chunked",
             "content-type" => "application/json",
                     "date" => "Thu, 09 Feb 2023 09:07:18 GMT",
               "keep-alive" => "timeout=60",
               "connection" => "keep-alive"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access the status code. When the underlying Manticore client is called, the status code is returned separately from the response headers. The http client [receives](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-http/blob/8dfe8fb1a1c40782cacd98de8dc7feddaae5b313/lib/logstash/filters/http.rb#L78) and tests the code, but does not store it in the event.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) is there any walk around? I am trying to do that, and just break it to another question [how to reuse logstash output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406083/how-to-reuse-the-output-of-logstash)